# Prime divisor of a variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

**Notation:** $k$ is an algebraically closed field. By a variety I mean a separated ringed space $(X,O_X)$ that is locally isomorphic to $(Z,\mathcal O_Z)$ where $Z\subseteq\mathbb A^n_k$ is a closed Zariski subset and $\mathcal O_U$ is the structural sheaf of regular functions.

---

Let $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ be  an irreducible variety; I've found two definitions for a prime divisor of $X$:

1. It is  a **closed** irreducible subvariety $Y$ of codimension $1$.
2. It is  an  irreducible subvariety $Y$ of codimension $1$.

Which of them do you prefer? why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where have you seen the definition of prime divisor without it being required to be closed?

Comment: For example on Milne's notes at page 195, but also on wikipedia at the voice "Weil divisor".

Comment: Sometimes subvarieties are defined to be closed. I've been to a course on complex manifolds where _submanifolds_ were assumed closed...

Comment: I would think one would always want it to be closed. For example, you would like for a prime divisor on an affine scheme $\mbox{Spec}(A)$ to correspond to a prime ideal of $A$; for this you need it to be closed.

Answer (score 3):

Prime divisors are closed by definition. See any introduction to algebraic geometry. If some texts doesn't write "closed", this is probably included in the definition of a "subvariety".